# Travis with Firebase deploy TypeError: this.stream.clearLine is not a function

Tags: firebase, travis-ci

I am trying to build & deploy a NodeJs + Python app with Travis.

This is approximately the folder structure (everything belongs to the same repo)

```
main/
├── angular2-client/
│   ├── dist/
│   ├── node_modules/
│   └── ...
├── django-server/
│    ├── server/
│    ├── manage.py
│    └── ...
├── .travis.yml
└── requirements.txt
```

and this is the `.travis.yml` file

```
language: python
python:
  - "3.4"
sudo: required
before_install:
  - nvm install node
  - npm --version
install:
  - cd ./angular2-client
  - npm install
  - cd ..
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
before_script:
  - npm install -g firebase-tools
script:
  - cd ./angular2-client && npm run build
after_success:
  - firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_API_TOKEN
before_deploy:
  - cd ..
  - cd ./django-server
deploy:
  provider: heroku
  api_key: $HEROKU_API_KEY
  app: glacial-shore-18891
```

After running the line `firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_API_TOKEN` Travis throws the error `**FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError: this.stream.clearLine is not a function**` and the deploy to Firebase fails.

I am having a problem with the Heroku deploy too, but I'll take care of that later.

Any hint on how to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same issue with Firebase + Travis starting with today's builds, and yesterday the issue was not present.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just had the same issue, it seems that some progress bar is making some issues. Try to disable it in non interactive mode:

```
after_success:
  - firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN --non-interactive
```

It solved my issue, hope it helps.