# Firebase Hosting use latest deployment

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I am using Github, Travis CI and Firebase hosting to test some CI features and get into that topic. Everything works so far, bust firebase never takes the latest deploy as hosting base.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOCbc.jpg

Is there any way to tell firebase to always use the latest deploy? Right now I have to reroll that latest the get the second latest active.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like travis-ci has an issue with the firebase deployment when it's not set to non-interactive.

[Solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44736576/travis-with-firebase-deploy-typeerror-this-stream-clearline-is-not-a-function)